# Java SE - storing currently logged in user details

Tags: java, authentication

Current approach in my Java SE app is to (once authenticated) store *only* the username as a system property, which I understand may have security implications

Whenever an action is attempted to be performed that requires a certain role, this username is used to make a call to the database to check whether the given user has the role.

I would prefer to load all the roles up front - then to check against some "User" object whether they were permitted for access. All of this needs to be done in a very controlled way, though.

Is there a standard approach / framework for this? Bare in mind I have already authenticated, and just want to store the user's details. **Would storing the currently logged in user as a Singleton be a sensible way to approach this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html) for authentication and authorization in your application. This framework is applicable for all java applications (Web,Standalone, Java EE etc)

Another option could be [Spring Security](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security). In Spring Security there is class [SecurityContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) where you can store the authentication status (Roles) once the user is authenticated. Later this could be use to verify user role when trying to access any operation. This should not be web application , you can use it in java SE.

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new RestUserAuthrity("ROLE_USER"));
CustomAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new CustomAuthenticationToken(authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
```

During the method call or where you want to check the role. Just get the role from SecurityContextHolder and verify appropriate role.

Comment: JAAS is *not* universally applicable in Java EE. It's a very low-level security framework for code base grants.

Comment: @MikeBraun, What is the java EE standard security? I'll suggest you to look deeper into JAAS to see what it provides. It is true that JAAS it not widely used.

Comment: I've looked pretty deep into JAAS. It's an ill match for Java EE. When you log into a JAAS login module, Java EE doesn't know about this. A Subject in JAAS is a collection of principals with no standardised mapping to the Java EE roles and user principal. You can integrate JAAS in Java EE via JASPIC, but this reduces JAAS to a fairly dumb name/role provider.

Comment: @MikeBraun, Not sure this might be related to your configuration. I have worked with JAAS custom login module and it works with IBM Webphere server

Comment: and it will most like ONLY work with IBM WebSphere. There just isn't any standardised mapping from a JAAS Subject to Java EE.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. As I can see the declarative security solves the problem in JEE platform. But what java provides to handle this in SE platform. This was the original point of discussion.

Comment: Well, declarative security is not the issue here. The problem is that JAAS puts many Principals in a Subject. One of those represents the user/caller name, but there's no standard which one that is. It may be a GroupPrincipal with name "foo" for server A, but a Principal with type com.vendor.UserPrincipal for server B. You just don't know. Declarative security comes much later in the process and is itself neither the problem nor the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use spring framework for session management as well as spring give you currently logged in users list then you can stored logged in users.

Comment: I think Spring is entirely too bloated a framework to be pushing it when all he needs is simple auth functions.

Comment: but if you use spring security this will be very simple